# Page does not reload new version everytime when load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

I realised my homepage always load the "last browsed content", even If I use private session or other fresh browser.

This is my HTML meta to force browser cache to load new session per use:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But, it doesn't seems working. I tested with Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: Are you using server side language(e.g. asp,php,jsp)?

Comment: New version of what? How is the content generated?

Comment: Perhaps you have caching module on your server that returns the same version until you do something or after some time.